# format.js argument

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, format, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a question about passing argument with format.js

There's my code (create method):

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end
```

I would like to know how can i get a variable value in my create.js.erb

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method is the same as in create.html.erb

```
<% @user.name %>
```

Comment: precisely it is <%= @...%>; <% %> will not output anything